# Logical Semantics, Information Extraction and Summarization

Tags: nlp, semantics, analysis, information-extraction, summarization

I want to know a general idea about these questions, in the field of data analysis and NLP. 
What are the steps included? If I want to retrieve the meaningful information from any domain-specific text and understand the general idea of any text.

Another question, the larger the size of the analyzed text the better is the result?

Excuse my ignorance. I want to understand more and it would help me a lot if you suggested some tutorials or readings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest "Speech and Language Processing" by Daniel Jurafsky & James H. Martin. The last chapters are about Information Extraction and Summarization.

As for your question about the text size, it depends. From my experience, Information Extraction works better with short sentences. However, you will need a large data set to train your system in recognizing relevant patterns.